# Custom Building Block Template wont load reliably

Tags: vba, ms-office, ms-word, word-2007

My small collection of document-specific macros and quickpart building blocks is growing! I'm starting to share these with employees, and am looking to be able to set up each remote computer once only. From there on, update collections on a network path. And because each computer looks to the shared location, everyone should always be working with up to date macros and quickparts etc.

So. What I already know:
- Required macros are saved in a separate module, ready to be shared/exported.
- Macros themselves occasionally reference local paths on my computer.
- I will need to reference paths with generic code or use Environ variables.
- Building blocks and quickparts are saved in a **separate** template file (currently located in Appdata, along with default building block file).

What I dont know:
a) How to point Word to a network path to retrieve macros from custom macro files. (Would I just have to import a fresh macro file at every important update, on each PC?)
b) What's the best way to load a building block item from a **CUSTOM** path?

My custom BuildingBlock template file is not loaded properly on occasion:

```
Dim objTemplate As Template
Dim objBB As BuildingBlock    

'set template to store the building block   
 Set objTemplate = Templates("C:\Users\[USER]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft_
\Document Building Blocks\1033\CustomBBlocks.dotx")

Set objBB = objTemplate.BuildingBlockEntries.Item("[EntryName]")
```

I know this because the code spits out a 'CollectionDoesntExist' error unless I click the Quickparts gallery prior to running the code for the first time. So it's like Word cant be bothered to open the template file and look inside unless I do it from the UI first.

Of course, if I first open the Quickparts gallery from the UI, prior to running my code, Word seems to figure it out, and inserts the correct Building Block entry without any issue.

Comment: hi @user3084170 was this answer helpful to solve your problem? If not please add what was not successful to your question. When the answer helped you, can you accept it by clicking the hollow green check mark next to it?

Answer (score 0):

In the past I've worked on a product that allows building blocks for Word too. Some sites have hundreds of templates and maybe 1.000 elements (see [Composition](http://www.invantive.com/products/invantive-composition)). The approach we've taken was successful and was different.

You are trying to deploy software elements (macros) across a large number of workstations. You can try to get it working using the possibilities of Microsoft Word and Windows, but it will be sensitive to problems when things change. For instance, switching to Office 2013, splitting a domain into two, work at home without VPN, etc.

Option 1 - DIY deployment: Better put the macros and other stuff behind a webpage, webservice or alike. Deploy on each workstation a generic program that pulls in everything and deploys it locally. You might want to hand over some parameters to the webpage being called to restrict the amount of data. You might want to cache things locally.

Option 2 - Use [ClickOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d%28v=vs.80%29.ASPX): write a clickonce deployment script, include the necessary references and put it on a shared network drive or http address. ClickOnce automagically upgrades your software when it finds a new version. It even works across the internet. And it does nothing when there is no new version.

Option 3 - Database: put the elements centrally in a database, allowing end users to change building blocks through forms. Have Microsoft Word in combination with a ClickOnce program pull them in.

For Composition we've used option 2 and 3.